# IntentService killed by system

Tags: android, sqlite, intentservice

I have an app where i can submit a timestatus to a server. 
To save battery I queue the statusitems in a `SQLite Database` and submit them periodically with a `JobScheduler` who starts an `IntentService` to the server.

The function to insert the items looks like this:

```
 public synchronized void workThroughQueue() {
    try {
        for (QueueItem queueItem : getAllQueueItems()) {
            try {
                dao.insert(queueItem.getItem());
                delete(queueItem);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Queueitem konnte nicht verarbeitet werden: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Queueverarbeitung nicht vollständig: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

The service (kotlin):

```
class QueueService : IntentService(QueueService::class.java.name) {

    override fun onHandleIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        Log.d("QueueService", "Jobservice started")
        TimerecordQueue().workThroughQueue()
        DangerAllowanceQueue().workThroughQueue()
        ProjektEndQueue().workThroughQueue()
        PhotoUploadQueue().workThroughQueue()
    }
}
```

My problem is, if the process gets killed by the system cause of low memory during `dao.insert(queueItem.getItem());` it sometimes gets successfully submitted to the server but it doesn't get deleted of the queue.

So the next time the queue starts it gets submitted again.

How can i resolve this problem?

Comment: what is dao.insert() is that webservice call?

Comment: yes, httpsrequest to a server

Comment: "submit them periodically with a JobScheduler who starts an IntentService to the server" -- why don't you have your `JobService` do this work? After all, your approach will not work on Android 8.0+, unless you make your `IntentService` be a foreground service, or unless you are *very* certain that `onHandleIntent()` will complete in less than a minute. Having this code in your `JobService` not only lets you tell the `JobScheduler` when the work is done, but it also gives you a longer window of time (~10 minutes) to complete the work and addresses the Android 8.0 background service limit.

Comment: i read somewhere that the jobservice runs in mainthread and a webrequest is not possible in mainthread?

Answer (score 0):

Well, in this case you can do one of the two things

1. In the service after insertion keep the insertion record locally(in your local database) as boolean flag as well. That will let you know for sure that your records were submitted successfully.
2. Second way is, when you are hitting a service, on server database before inserting record check that record is already exist. As I can see you are sending item. There should be some sort of item id. Check on server database if that record against item id exists if yes leave that record.
   This should do the trick.

Comment: The server itselfs checks if the record exists and does not insert it if so.
But imho I don't think thats "clean"

Comment: but it makes sure the data is not inserted again as a duplicate record

Comment: yep, the server does this